# get request only returns id and not the full element with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean

I am building a mean stack app.

When I use this :

```
router.get('/courses/:course', function (req, res) {
    res.json(req.course);
});
```

I get back the full object. But when I do this :

```
router.get('/courses/:course/reviews', function (req, res){
    res.json(req.course.reviews);
});
```

I only get back the reviews ID, not the full elements like I whished it did.

Any idea why ?

EDIT :

Answering questions :

here is router.param :

```
router.param('course', function (req, res, next, id) {
    var query = Course.findById(id);

    query.exec(function (err, course){
        if(err) { return next(err);}
        if(!course) {return next(new Error('can\'t find course'));}

        req.course = course;
        return next();
    });
});
```

Course is a model :

```
var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code: String,
    name: String,
    courseContentGrade: Number,
    courseTeachingGrade: Number,
    courseAverage: Number,
    reviews: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'review'}]
});
```

Comment: Where do you get `course` object from and how does it look?

Comment: Please show the `router.param()` function that sets `req.course`

Comment: If you want to access anything via a route param you need to access it using `req.params.<field>` so in your example you need to do `req.params.course` to access the value passed into course.

Comment: If you're storing reviews references in course, probably you'll need to use mongoose.populate(), but we need more details in order discover what's going on. As @VsevolodGoloviznin asked, how do you get req.course?

Comment: answered in EDIT.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to populate the review field using mongoose.populate().

Below is a revised router.param, note the addition of the populate method to the query.

```
router.param('course', function (req, res, next, id) {
    var query = Course.findById(id).populate('reviews');

    query.exec(function (err, course){
        if(err) { return next(err);}
        if(!course) {return next(new Error('can\'t find course'));}

        req.course = course;
        return next();
    });
});
```

Documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: hi,

I used your solution but nothing changed. I still only get back the review's ID.

Comment: @Puck7 Please try again, I've edited the post and changed 'review' to 'reviews'

Comment: hi, it worked thanks ! I'm sorry I didn't read your solution properly the first time to spot the 's'. I have a new error though. When I curl to get the reviews, I get an error message telling me the review schema is not registered. I'll open a new question thanks :)

Comment: Great, it's possible you need to pluralise 'reviews' in the refs parameter in your course schema.  Mongoose automatically pluralises the names of collections.

Comment: hey, I added an s to ref in course and it suppressed my error. But now when I curl to get the review, I don't have an error but an empy [] although the course already has several reviews (I can see them if I curl to get all courses) any suggestions ? :)

Comment: The same thing happen when I curl http://localhost:3000/courses/{course.id} I get back the course and inside, I only have : "reviews":[]

But if I curl http://localhost:3000/courses I get all my courses and in each courses I have : "reviews":["review.id","review2.id"]. Do you have any idea or should I open a new question ? (I'm relatively knew to stackoverflow and I'm still unsure about best practices)

Comment: Probably best in a new question. Make sure you post all your routes and schemas (especially '/course') and I'll take look.